# jquery: drop-down boxes floating over modal dialog with IE6

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog, internet-explorer-6

I've got a web form with various html fields. There is a textbox input field which is wired to work as follows:

- when it attains focus a modal dialog should showup asking user for confirmation.

I've used jquery ui on my page. Hence I've adopted a jquery UI modal dialog to show up here. The problem is when the dialog is "modal" the dropdown boxes seem to be floating above the modal div which shows up. It even floats above the dialog itself.

I've tried the solution mentioned in the thread: [jQuery UI modal dialog sliding behind dropdownlists in IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740057/jquery-ui-modal-dialog-sliding-behind-dropdownlists-in-ie6)

ps: I've downloaded the bgiframe.js source code from [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#5tHPZ2EB8jc/trunk/jquery/bgiframe/1.0/bgiframe.js&q=bgiframe.js%20jquery&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc): Hope its the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer elsewhere on StackOverflow, but found this unanswered questions first, so for the sake of others with this issue.

On IE6, it's old and pants, but someone has made a nice javascript file to use and it solves the problem

visit here

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe#Download

Strangely, I only had to add that script file to my Master MVC page and the problem was solved, didn't even had to set bgiframe to true! so try that first yourself.